# Where can I play Quantum Chess online for free?

Tags: chess-variants, online-chess

I saw some videos featuring a chess variant called Quantum Chess on YouTube. It looked very interesting to me, so I decided to try to find it online for free, but I couldn’t. Does anyone know of such a place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [truly quantum chess](https://truly-quantum-chess.sloppy.zone). It is an implementation of quantum chess by yours truly, the rules are sligtly different from the rules of the steam version though, for example, pawns can quantum move.

Comment: The link is down, but you can get the code and run it in https://github.com/caphindsight/TrulyQuantumChess if you have technical knowledge.

Comment: @PhoneixS sorry about that, fixed the link.